# I'm totally new to AE. What are some things typically done to clean up video and make it look nice?

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I shot some wedding footage for a friend when her video guy was unable to make it at the last minute. I use LR and PS all the time but I have no experience with video at all beyond some basic time lapse stuff. I have AE and PP but know next to nothing about the latter and not much more about the former. What kinds of things are typically done to a video to make it look nice? I shot the ceremony on a handy cam on a tripod while I roamed hand-holding a 7D. I shot the reception with the 7D on a tripod; collapsed, monopod style.

Thanks!

Comment: No love? I'm a sad panda. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common postproduction work:

- Color Correction
- Reframing (crop out unwanted stuff from images, especially viable if shot in a higher resolution then distribution format)
- Stabilization
- Speed Changes and Speed Ramps

Personally i doubt that you need to use After Effects for this though, as all of that can also be done in Premiere. If you want to learn After Effects in the process, i'd look into making some nice typography animations which you later import into the final video. There are tons of tutorials on that on the interwebs and / or you can download some After Effects templates to get you started.